# Issue in admin enqueue scripts file include in my plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am facing issue with admin_enqueue_scripts()

However when I am using below

```
<script src=""> && <link rel="stylesheet">
```

it works perfectly. The code below is what I have included this to my menu and submenu pages.

```
    <script src="<?php echo plugins_url( 'assets/js/vue.min.js', __FILE__ ); ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo plugins_url( 'assets/js/axios.min.js', __FILE__ );?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo plugins_url( 'assets/js/jquery.min.js', __FILE__ );?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo plugins_url( 'assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', __FILE__ );?>"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo plugins_url( 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css', __FILE__ ); ?>"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo plugins_url( 'assets/css/native-divice.min.css', __FILE__ );?>"/>
```

But when I use below enqueue based on your instructions, I am not able to run the code.

```
function lt_scr_lambdatest_scripts_styles()
{
  wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );  
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery', plugins_url('assets/js/jquery.min.js', __FILE__), array(), null);
  wp_enqueue_script('lt_scr_lambdatest_vue_min_js', plugins_url('assets/js/vue.min.js', __FILE__), array(), null);

  wp_enqueue_script('lt_scr_lambdatest_axios_min_js', plugins_url('assets/js/axios.min.js', __FILE__), array(), null);

  wp_enqueue_script('lt_scr_lambdatest_bootstrap_min_js', plugins_url('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), null);

  wp_register_style('lt_scr_lambdatest_bootstrap_min_css', plugins_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css', __FILE__), array(), null);
  wp_enqueue_style('lt_scr_lambdatest_bootstrap_min_css');
  wp_register_style('lt_scr_lambdatest_native_divice_min_css', plugins_url('assets/css/native-divice.min.css', __FILE__), array(), null);
  wp_enqueue_style('lt_scr_lambdatest_native_divice_min_css');
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'lt_scr_lambdatest_scripts_styles');
```

Let me know if you need any further information.

Look forward to your assistance here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
function lt_scr_lambdatest_scripts_styles(){

  wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );  
  wp_register_script('jquery', plugins_url('assets/js/jquery.min.js', __FILE__), array(), null);
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

  wp_enqueue_script('lt_scr_lambdatest_vue_min_js', plugins_url('assets/js/vue.min.js', __FILE__), array(), null);

  wp_enqueue_script('lt_scr_lambdatest_axios_min_js', plugins_url('assets/js/axios.min.js', __FILE__), array(), null);

  wp_enqueue_script('lt_scr_lambdatest_bootstrap_min_js', plugins_url('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), null);

  wp_register_style('lt_scr_lambdatest_bootstrap_min_css', plugins_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css', __FILE__), array(), null);
  wp_enqueue_style('lt_scr_lambdatest_bootstrap_min_css');
  wp_register_style('lt_scr_lambdatest_native_divice_min_css', plugins_url('assets/css/native-divice.min.css', __FILE__), array(), null);
  wp_enqueue_style('lt_scr_lambdatest_native_divice_min_css');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'lt_scr_lambdatest_scripts_styles');
```